# Apache poi - Remove first row in excel and save it to the same file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Hello i need help with this, i tried about 30 tutorials last few hours and i dont know how to solve it:

1. Open Excel File
2. Delete and remove row "A" ( to be replaced in for later by excel row B,C,D,...)
3. Rewrite opened Excel File ( because if program crash for high usage i need to have stored last value, and start program again without searching and deleting which was used ... )

---

```
OPCPackage fileInputStream = OPCPackage.open(new File("input.xlsx"));
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
        XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        worksheet.shiftRows(0, 0, 1);
        workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("input.xlsx"));
```

---

This code dont remove row a and dont save file to the same location ...

Could anybody help me please?

Thank you FJ

Comment: The question is not clear to me. What is meant with "excel row A,B,C,D"? In my Excel A,B,C,D are columns and not rows.

Comment: @AxelRichter sorry i mean excel row 1,2,3,4,5...

- Read row 1 (value_a)
- Delete row 1 (value_a)
- Read row 1 (value_b)
- Delete row 1 (value_b)
...

Answer (score 2):

First problem in your code:

The `worksheet.shiftRows(0, 0, 1);` shifts first row one row downwards. If the need is removing first row, then second row up to last row should be shifted one row upwards. This would be `worksheet.shiftRows(1, worksheet.getLastRowNum(), -1);`.

Second problem in your code:

If  a `File` is used for creating a `Workbook` then the workbook cannot be written into the same file. This is because the `File` used stays opened until the workbook will be closed. So we should not using a `File` here for opening the workbook but a `FileInputStream` instead.

Working example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

class ReadExcelRemoveRowAndWrite {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("input.xlsx"));

  Sheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  worksheet.shiftRows(1, worksheet.getLastRowNum(), -1);

  workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("input.xlsx"));
  workbook.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you for example :) but if i create the same workbook it ends because "file already exist". So what i need is read database from excel, and always remove row after use. if is not possible with apache poi i can try use selenium and google drive instead of it.